# Displaying computer name and free disk space in powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I'm running the following powershell command :

```
 $cmd = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName Drex -Class Win32_volume |  Where {($_.DriveLetter) -and ($_.FreeSpace)}| ft -auto DriveLetter,FreeSpace 
 $cmd
```

It gives as result

```
DriveLetter    FreeSpace
 -----------    ---------
 D:           39295995904
 C:          297391972352
```

I need to have an additional column that contains computer name 
How can i do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$cmd = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName Drex -Class Win32_volume |  Where {($_.DriveLetter) -and ($_.FreeSpace)}| ft -auto DriveLetter,FreeSpace, __SERVER
```

`PSComputerName` also works instead of `__SERVER`

Comment: Careful using the code tag. It was treating the `_`'s like the italics short form

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [calculated property](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx):

```
$ComputerName = 'Drex'
$Disks = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $ComputerName -Class Win32_volume |  Where {($_.DriveLetter) -and ($_.FreeSpace)}
$Disks | Select-Object DriveLetter,FreeSpace,@{Label="Computername";Expression={$ComputerName}}
```

Also, `ft` (an alias for `Format-Table`) provides a formatted string - you want to avoid storing formatted output in variables - wait until you want to display your data before you pipe to formatting cmdlets

Comment: Second against the saving of `Format-Cmdlets`